# Helm chart usage

Tags: github, kubernetes, containers, microservices, kubernetes-helm

i'm working on a kubernetes project where we have a each micro service with it's own helm chart, currently the helm chart of each microservice is with it in the code source repository, and now i want to create a qa environnement where the same code can be used but i'm having a problem customizing the helm chart for each environnement, my question is what is the best approach to handle a helm chart for a microservice?and should the helm chart be located in the repository of the source code?

thanks in advance

Comment: You can customize the chart during deployment using `values`.  Have you tried that? https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/values_files/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's ok to have the chart in each microservice's repository.

Now, to deploy your system (no matter the environment), you need to `helm install` all those charts. How can you do this? You have two options, either you individually install each one, or the best approach, you create a meta chart.

What's this meta chart? Just another dummy chart, with dependencies to all of your microservices. So that you end up with something like:

```
apiVersion: v3
name: myservice
version: 1.0.0

dependencies:
- name: microserviceA
  version: ">=1.0.0"
  repository: "path_to_microserviceA_repo"
- name: microserviceB
  version: ">=1.0.0"
  repository: "path_to_microserviceA_repo"
```

Then, ideally you would have different values files with configuration for each environment you're going to deploy: QA, staging, production, personal for local development, etc